# How to write a dataframe without using pandas or any package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm studying phyton and one of my goals is write most os my codes without packages, and I would to like write a structure which looks like with pandas's DataFrame, but without using any other package. Is there any way to do that?

Using pandas, my code looks like this:

```
From pandas import Dataframe

...

s = DataFrame(s, index = ind)
```

where `ind` is the result of a function.

Maybe dictionary could be the answer?

Thanks

Comment: I am curious as to why you would want to write your own code without packages ? packages are normally well maintained and efficiently tuned librarys developed by people with sginificant amount of expereince in python. They are well tested and cover most edge cases. Why would you want to get rid of all that and write your own? also this question in its current form doesnt fit the SO requirement as it will broadly be opinion based

Comment: How could you have a `dataframe` without using `pandas`? You'd be using it whether you realize it or not.

Answer (score 1):

No native python data structure has all the features of a pandas dataframe, which was part of why pandas was written in the first place. Leveraging packages others have written brings the time and work of many other people into your code, advancing your own code's capabilities in a similar way that Isaac Newton said his famous discoveries were only possible by standing on the shoulders of giants.

There's no easy summary for your answer except to point out that pandas is open-source, and their implementation of the dataframe can be found at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.

Comment: Just use the libraries that are out there and available for free.  A few months back, I had an interview question about this very same thing.  I hung up on the interviewer when he told me I couldn't use any Python libraries.  There is no point in reinventing the wheel, which was created and perfected a long time ago.